# Replace custom tags with <a href> tags

Tags: regex, vb.net, asp.net-4.5

In my ASP.NET application I have a plain text field.  I want to allow the user to be able to enter URL's in the following format:

```
[url="http://www.google.com"]Google[/url]
```

These would be saved to a database directly as they were entered.  On retrieveal however, I'd like to convert the above into the following HTML format to make it active on-screen:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

The reason for this approach is to avoid tampering with the built-in ASP.NET validation routines, which trigger an error when it sees `<a` in a form input string.

I've seen other examples on StackOverflow where RegEx is used to parse the string, however, I cannot find anything that I can follow where multiple occurrences of `[url...]` may exist in a single string.

Can anyone please offer me an example of how to parse such a string, say...

> Try this funky new search engine:
>   [url="http://www.google.com"]Google[/url] Or this older one from back
>   in the day: [url="http://uk.altavista.com"]AltaVista[/url]

...to convert each occurrence into the desired format?  RegEx isn't my strong-point sadly.

Thanks.

Comment: Almost similar question I answered [in the regex chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9370083#9370083) but in PHP. If there is a similar function in ASP you may just replace `size` with `url` and the output ... Also I think there is a typo `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</url>` I think you meant `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks yes there was a typo - corrected.  As for the RegEx, in VB.NET it doesn't return a match.  Not sure if the double-quotes interfere (that is the string symbol in VB.NET) so you use double-double-quotes to return a single double-quote in a string if that makes sense?! `Dim r As New Regex("/\[url\s?=\s?""?(.*?)""?\](.*?)\[\/url\]/s")`

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB.net or ASP, here's a screenshot from an [online tester](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L2eL5.jpg), you might join us in [the regex room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex).

Comment: Hi.  Can you paste your comments into an answer?  Not only have you helped me solve this but I've learned a ton of new stuff and want to accept it as the answer for other peoples' use.

Comment: lol, great that it helped you, makes me more motivated to help people here :D Ah I'm tired to put it as an answer since I removed the regex, you may put it as an answer and accept it yourself ! Happy Coding and +1 for the efforts :)

Comment: Wicked.  Just applying the new logic to my real project - very happy with this result.  Keep up the good work :-)

Comment: Quick point...  Is it also possible to use the RegEx pattern and output pattern in Javascript/JQuery?  Thanks again :-)

Comment: Yes ofcourse, here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Wce/) also you may take a look at those answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519842/regular-expression-end-tag-start-tag) since I saw that you're using *almost* the same pattern as the one that asked the question.

Comment: Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525087 you deserve an accepted answer after your efforts!

Comment: Thanks but you don't have to go that far :)

Answer (score 1):

Following HamZa DzCyberDeV's comments I used the RegEx pattern within [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/) and found RegExHero even generated the ASP.NET. Therefore the simple code below exactly achieves the outcome I needed:

```
Dim s As String = txt_input.Text.Trim
Dim strRegex As String = "\[url\s?=\s?""?(.*?)""?\](.*?)\[\/url\]"
Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex)
Dim strReplace As String = "<a href=""$1"">$2</a>"
ltl_output.Text = myRegex.Replace(s, strReplace)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you need a BBCode converter for ASP.NET, which you can find [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/531089/BBCode-for-ASP-NET-BBCode-Net).

Example from given link:

```
string BBCodeSyntax = "[url={webaddress}]{display}[/url]"; 
string HtmlSyntax = "<a href=\"{webaddress}\">{display}</a>"; 
string Fields = "{webaddress};{display}"; 

string input = "For those who code - [url=http://www.codeproject.com]The CodeProject[/url]. This website contains lots of articles about programming. For open source project hosting from Microsoft, you may have a look at [url=http://www.codeplex.com]Codeplex.com[/url]."; 

string output = BBCode.ConvertToHtml(input, BBCodeSyntax, HtmlSyntax, Fields); 
return output;
```

Comment: Hi.  I appreciate that, and have also seen Jeff Atwood's markdown NuGet package, which imitates StackOverflow's editor.  However, each come with their own problems (BBCode uses iFrames which aren't good), so I'm looking to do this using native ASP.NET functionality if possible, e.g. RegEx

Comment: in BBCodeSyntax you give a syntax of your custom BBCode, in HTMLSytax you provide your custom HTML syntax where you can write iframe if you want, but in given example html syntax is simple link only with href attribute and text to display.