# Replace [url] tags with <a href> tags in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to use JQuery to achieve the following logic:

- Replace the string value of `[url="http://www.google.com"]Google[/url]` with `<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`

Please see my HTML page below.  The problem is that on pressing the button, the orignal text is just pasted and no RegEx replacements are made.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        function processJs() {
            var oldtext = $("#oldtext").html();
            var newtext = oldtext.replace('\[url\s?=\s?"?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/url\]', '<a href="$1">$2</a>');
            $('#mydiv').html(newtext);
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="oldtext">
            Try this funky new search engine:
            [url="http://www.google.com"]Google[/url]
            Or this older one from back in the day:
            [url="http://uk.altavista.com"]AltaVista[/url]
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btn" value="Replace" onclick="processJs(); return false;" />
        </div>
        <div id="mydiv" style="background-color: #eeeeee; border: 2px inset #aaaaaa">
            Replaced text will go here.
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've had this RegEx pattern work using ASP.NET, so I'm not sure where the problem lies when ported to JavaScript...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not a valid regex. Use `/` as modifiers:

```
/\[url\s?=\s?"?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/url\]/
```

making the function:

```
function processJs() {
    var oldtext = $("#oldtext").html();
    var newtext = oldtext.replace(/\[url\s?=\s?"?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/url\]/g, '<a href="$1">$2</a>');
    $('#mydiv').html(newtext);
}
```

`g` at the end will repeat it over the text. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xe2F9/

Comment: Stunning.  Answered so quickly that StackOverflow won't even allow me to accept it for another 7 minutes :-D

Answer (score 4):

```
var newtext = oldtext.replace(/\[url\s?=\s?"?(.*?)"?\](.*?)\[\/url\]/g, '<a href="$1">$2</a>');
```

You specify the 'search' as a RegEx object - not a string.

Just using /.../ will automatically crate one transparently.

Comment: What's the trailing /g for please?

Comment: @EvilDr it means match all (this is JS specific)

Comment: 'cos you want to replace all matches, not just the first.

Comment: "global" - ie, replace all occurrences, not just the first one.